# Monitor file association change?

Tags: windows, file-association, event-log

On Windows, I want to check to see when a file association was changed, and who or what triggered this change.

For example: If I change the .PDF file association from Microsoft Edge to Adobe Reader, is this logged somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to monitor file-type changes is to use a specialized product,
such as :

- [Registry Live Watch](http://leelusoft.altervista.org/registry-live-watch.html)
  with a [review here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/registry-live-watch-track-changes-registry) (free)
- [MJ Registry Watcher](https://jacobsm.com/mjsoft.htm#rgwtchr) (free)
- [WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/) (commercial) with a
  [tutorial](http://www.winpatrol.com/filetype.html)

You may also enable registry auditing to the Event Viewer by :

- Run within an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) the command :

  ```
  auditpol /set /subcategory:"Registry" /success:enable
  ```
- Launch `regedit`
- Right-click `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the left-hand pane and select
  *Permissions > Advanced*.
- Click the *Auditing* tab and select Add.
- Click *Select a principal*, type `Everyone` in the `Enter the object name` box and click OK.
- Choose whether you want auditing to apply to this keys, or subkeys too
- Click `Show advanced permissions`
- Check `Set value` to monitor value changes
- Click OK to close all open dialogs.